# Sort JSON Object

Tags: javascript

How to sort JSON object in javascript?

```
obj = JSON.parse(count);   //count is responseText
```

and

```
count= {"MH_YTML":"Yavatmal H.O","MH_WRDH":"Wardha H.O","MH_SWTW":"Sawantwadi H.O"}  //count{key,value}
```

I want to sort count value(Yavatmal H.O, Wardha H.O and Sawantwadi H.O) by ascending order.

Comment: In objects, order doesn't matter. If order matters, you need an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting json objects by specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416691/sorting-json-objects-by-specific-value)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript objects (and their JSON representation, where relevant) have no order. They are unordered bags of property names and values.

You could create an array with entries in a specific order.

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort an object. However you can create an array and sort it. Something like this:

```
var count= {"MH_YTML":"Yavatmal H.O", "MH_WRDH":"Wardha H.O", "MH_SWTW":"Sawantwadi H.O"},
    countArr = [];

for (var i in count) {
    countArr.push({key: i, val: count[i]});
}
countArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.val < b.val) return -1;
    if (a.val > b.val) return 1;
    return 0; 
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/8S4aD/1/

Comment: +1 for doing an implementation (though really that's the OP's task), but your `sort` callback is wrong. It needs to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: You've implemented a *reverse* sort, was that your intention?

Comment: @dfsq in `countArr.push({key: i, val: count[i]});
` for your code its taking key as 1,2,3...so on and for values its taking one single letter as a value "{,M,H,_... so on}".   I want here is `key="MH_YTML"` and value should be `value="Yavatmal H.O"`

Comment: @user1745252 Why 1,2,3? `keys` will be `MH_YTML`, `MH_WRDH`, `MH_SWTW`. And values are `Yavatmal H.O`, `Wardha H.O`. Check the fiddle, `console.log(countArr)` to see new structure.

Comment: @dfsq I am not able to access fiddle

Comment: Works for me. Doesn't it load or what?

Answer (score 1):

At first convert that object to array, where each array element will be a pair of key & value from object, then sort that array using custom function by values. You can then convert it back to object, but you can't guarantee that object properties order will be kept same.