# Sorting json objects by specific value

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I am sending data that I have already sorted by number of counts, from my controller in Laravel to my script file. Json data that I am sending looks like this:

```
{"5":{"title":"Coop post title","summary":"dbsbsb","count":5},
 "7":{"title":"Example article","summary":"fdsbdfsbsffd","count":5},
 "6":{"title":"Coop's post","summary":"sdbadbb","count":3},
 "0":{"title":"sdvsdv","summary":"dsvsdv","count":2},
 "4":{"title":"sdvsdv","summary":"dsvsdv","count":1}}
```

But when I parse json data like this in my script file data gets random again:

```
var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(cleanData);
```

And then I get in console data that looks like this:

```
Object {0: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object}
  0:Object
    count:2
    summary:"dsvsdv"
    title:"sdvsdv"
    __proto__:Object
  4:Object
    count:1
    summary: "dsvsdv"
    title: "sdvsdv"
    __proto__:Object
  5:Object
    count:5
    summary: "dbsbsb"
    title: "Coop post title"
    __proto__: Object
  6:Object
    count:3
    summary: "sdbadbb"
    title: "Coop's post"
    __proto__: Object
  7:Object
    count:5
    summary: "fdsbdfsbsffd"
    title: "Example article"
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: You cannot sort the properties of an object, so your question is moot. If you want to guarantee the order of the objects you would *have* to use an array.

Comment: I found a good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222690/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: It is way better create a json containing an array of objects and simply visit it with a loop, or ES2016 .map method..

Comment: Show the data that you encode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166518/parsejson-sorts-my-json-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort using [lodash#sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy):

`_.sortBy(collection, [iteratees=[_.identity]])`

Creates an array of elements, sorted in ascending order by the results of running each element in a `collection` (Array|Object) thru each iteratee. This method performs a stable sort, that is, it preserves the original sort order of equal elements. The iteratees are invoked with one argument: (value).

```js
var cleanData = {"5":{"title":"Coop post title","summary":"dbsbsb","count":5},"7":{"title":"Example article","summary":"fdsbdfsbsffd","count":5},"6":{"title":"Coop's post","summary":"sdbadbb","count":3}, "0":{"title":"sdvsdv","summary":"dsvsdv","count":2}, "4":{"title":"sdvsdv","summary":"dsvsdv","count":1}};

cleanData = _.sortBy(cleanData, ['count']);
console.log(cleanData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get _ is not defined when I am trying to copy your code

Comment: Seems like it is sorting it now, but now it is doing it in asc order, how to make it so that it is in desc order?

Comment: Found it:   cleanData = _.orderBy(cleanData, ['count'], ['desc']);

Comment: To get desc: `cleanData = _.sortBy(cleanData, ['count']).reverse();`